# Dropbox on Ubuntu without screen

Tags: ubuntu, display, dropbox

I'm trying to use `Dropbox` on my `Ubuntu 14.04` and I've a very strange behavior.

When I installed the computer, everything is alright. But when I use my computer without plugging a monitor, `Dropbox` won't start anymore.

I've force a resolution but it's not working. Here is a screenshot (in french, sorry in advance) where you can see that there isn't any monitor plugged.

[image: Screenshot of my machine (throw <code>TeamViewer</code>) without any monitor]

Does anyone have an idea to start `Dropbox` without monitor?

Here are command line (and result) that I've done:

```
dropbox start
#Starting Dropbox...Dropbox isn't running!
#Done!
dropbox status
#Dropbox isn't running!
```

This is happening with `Ubuntu 14.04` but not with `Debian 7.7.0`

Thank you in advance